# how to use the hook processUpload_postProcessAction in my extension?

Tags: typo3, hook

Can anyone here know how to use the processUpload_postProcessAction hook in my extension?

I have created a hook folder and added a php file named *class.tx_lms_tcemain.php*

I have added the following lines in my extension's ext_localconf.php

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processUploadClass'][] = 'EXT:wr_dw_lms/hooks/class.tx_lms_tcemain.php:tx_lms_tcemain';
```

In the PHP file inside hooks folder contains following code:

```
    <?php
class tx_lms_tcemain {
            function processUpload_postProcessAction (&$filename, t3lib_TCEmain
$parentObject) {
$this->addFlashMessage(
'Blog created successfully!',
'Status',
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\AbstractMessage::OK,TRUE
);
           }

    }
?>
```

This one does not work. My code is not getting executed. Can anyone here help me?

Comment: What TYPO3 version are you using?

Comment: the version is 6.2.10

Answer (score 1):

Try to write this in your ext_localconf.php

`$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_extfilefunc.php']['processData'][] = 'Vendor\WrDwLms\Hooks\Tcemain\';`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code in `ext_localconf.php` to

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processUpload'][] = 'EXT:wr_dw_lms/hooks/class.tx_lms_tcemain.php:tx_lms_tcemain';
```

Note the "processUpload" instead of the "processUploadClass".

I'd recommend however you use proper namespacing:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['t3lib/class.t3lib_tcemain.php']['processUploadClass'][] =
    'Vendor\WrDwLms\Hooks\Tcemain';
```

Your Hook could look like this (put it in `wr_dw_lms/Classes/Hooks/`):

```
namespace Vendor\WrDwLms\Hooks;
use TYPO3\CMS\Core\DataHandling\DataHandler

class Tcemain {
    public function processUpload_postProcessAction(&$filename, DataHandler $parentObject) {
        ....
    }
}
```

*Edit: as for the code you edited into your question (`$this->addFlashMessage()`) that of course cannot work if you do not implement the method in your class.*

Comment: how to debug to see if it works or not? can I use echo statement ?